# MySQL incorrect order of DECIMAL?

Tags: mysql

When I select data from a MySQL table and order it by a `DECIMAL` column `DESCENDING`, this is the order:

```
3, 2, 1, -1, 0
```

Why is this so?

How to correctly set the order so that it is:

`3, 2, 1, 0, -1` ?

**EDIT**
Actually, the problem is with NULL data. This is the order it does:

```
3, 2, 1, -1, NULL, NULL
```

This is the desired order:

```
3, 2, 1, NULL, NULL, -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `COALESCE` in your `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY COALESCE(columnName, 0) DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93450/1)

Comment: You sir, are God to me! Works like a charm!!

Comment: @user7282's answer is more straightforward

Answer (score 0):

use the following syntax for that

```
ORDER BY column DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ordering by a column with nulls, they always end up at the beginning or end of your results. Null means unknown, not zero.

If you want to treat them as zero you can use `ifnull(column, 0)` in your select statement.